# gridcontrol shrink after changing display settings

Tags: devexpress, windows-8.1, gridcontrol

after at windows 8.1 on the desktop right click menu personalize-> display changed the items size medium %125, on the application the devexpress tool gridcontrol was shrink like the image. without the size changing the items looks really small. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Have you set the GridControl.Dock property to DockStyle.Fill or DockStyle.Top? This way the control always uses the whole width.

Comment: Thanks but dock property is already fill. the grid fills on the small display (%100 size) but on this display size it doesnt, so the blank area shows up on the form.

Comment: Cannot it be related to the problem discussed here? http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B134833